# LibGDX all assets as one file

Tags: java, libgdx

I've heard about special type of file in libgdx to store all assets just in one file as archive. What is the name of this class and where I can find any examples.

Greetings

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you need. If you mean a file with all texture assets, it has to be the TextureAtlas class. However, what you need has to be here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets

Comment: All assets like OGG Files, PNG Files, Script Files, Text files etc.

Comment: There is a class to manage all types of assets: AssetManager. It loads, gets and frees all resources as wavs, pngs and mp3. Is it what you are asking for?

Comment: AFAIK there is no "ligdx special file" for this. However, it is something you could easily create yourself using standard java functionality.
However, before answering a question that might result in suboptimal final solution. What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: Ok, I find out it's simple zip file format. Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38018352/couldnt-load-textureatlas-from-zip-archive-via-assetmanager-libgdx